# Primeng: absolute position not working after adding p-selectButton

Tags: html, css, typescript, primeng

I'm new to primeng, i had this html code

```
<div class="main wheel">
    <div class="wheel-part use">
       <img src="./assets/images/svg/path-use.svg">
       <span class="wheel-part-title">USE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.wheel {
    height: 37.5vh;
    width: 39vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #008800;
  }

  .wheel .use {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

And this was the output:

[image]

My problem is that on adding a **p-selectButton** to my html, the position absolute is no more working and i can't figure out why.

The html code after adding **p-selectButton**:

```
<div class="main wheel">
   <p-selectButton [options]="wheelParts" multiple="multiple" >
      <ng-template let-wheelPart let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
         <div class="wheel-part use">
            <img src="./assets/images/svg/path-use.svg">
            <span class="wheel-part-title">USE</span>
         </div>
      </ng-template>
   </p-selectButton>
</div>
```

Result after adding **p-selectButton**:

[image]

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-suvc3v?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my answer with StackBlitz

Comment: Hmm... I can't see the problem in your StackBlitz, the `p-selectButton` appears on the top right as you wish, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, i was doing some modifications, check now please

Comment: Just to be sure, you'd like to set the `p-selectbutton` on the top right corner?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the  `<div class="wheel-part use">` to inside your primeNg element, the class it not accessible in the same way. To get to it now, you must use `:host ::ng-deep`

The stackblitz appears to be out of date, so I cannot experiment to tell you the exact syntax, but try something like

```
  :host ::ng-deep .use {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
```